# Transition animation does not works properly on Safari

Tags: javascript, css

I used CSS transition for create the Fade Up animation effect. Here is the code:

```
.animation-up{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
    transform: translateY(100px);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease;
    transition: -webkit-transform .6s ease;
    -o-transition: transform .6s ease;
    transition: transform .6s ease;
    transition: transform .6s ease,-webkit-transform .6s ease;
 }
 
.animation-up.active {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0);
    transform: translate(0);
 }
```

For addding active to the block I used:

```
function animations() {
    
    appear({
        elements: function elements(){
            return document.getElementsByClassName('appear');
        },
        appear: function appear(el){
            var item = $(el);
            item.addClass('active');
        },
        bounds: 0,
        reappear: true
    });
}
```

And this animation works well on Firefox, Opera, and of course Chrome. But there is some issue on iPhone. Here is example: https://gyazo.com/1bd0bdb42fd7d043b404cd868b35e90b as you can see the block Fade Up but after disappears and reappears. Maybe the JavaScript cause the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple transition css properties and the last one will overwrite thr previouse ones.
You can comma seperate the transition targets like this:

```
transition: width 2s, height 4s;
```

So in your example it would be

```
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease, transform .6s ease;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease, transform .6s ease;
transition: opacity 1s ease, transform .6s ease;
```